# How to move the outputs to bazel cache to use for remote execution

Tags: bazel, googletest, bazel-remote-cache

I have a bazel toolchain which will run some external test kit with the help of a shell script.
Currently the outputs will be save in the Workspace folder directly via script.

I want to extend this to other users via Remote Cache and Remote execution.

Is there a way to implement this by providing the cache infra for my test kit.

I understand the steps are like to move the outputs to a cache path, but I am failed to achieve that.

Can you please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the files in `$TEST_UNDECLARED_OUTPUTS_DIR` (an environment variable Bazel sets when running tests), then the files will be zipped and uploaded to the remote cache.

It looks like there's a [`--nozip_undeclared_test_outputs`](https://bazel.build/reference/command-line-reference#flag--zip_undeclared_test_outputs) flag which is supposed to avoid zipping them, but I see several open bugs about that not working as intended.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer. I see the value of the variable is empty. I went through the docs and I understand that I need to set the value by export in the terminal before bazel test. But I am unable to confirm that whether it's caching.